# Unity configuration and nested generic types

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm new to Unity and have a problem with configuration and nested generic types in a WCF service. Everything has been working fine until I hit the situation where I needed to define a factory which returns instances of types based on a generic interface.

The code looks something like this:

```
public interface IFactory<T, TResult>
{
    TResult CreateInstance(T input);
}

public interface IFilter<T>
{
    // throws an exception if an item is to be filtered
    void Filter(T itemToFilter);
}

// classes implementing this interface can have multiple filters    
public interface IFilterRunner<T>
{        
    void RunFilters(T itemToFilter);
}

public class FilterRunnerFactory : IFactory<BaseType, IFilterRunner<BaseType>>
{
    public IFilterRunner<BaseType> CreateInstance(BaseType input)
    {
        if (input is SubType)
        {
            return new SubTypeFilterRunner();
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not create an IFilterRunner for the input.");
    }
}

public class Service
{
    private readonly IFactory<BaseType, IFilterRunner<BaseType>> _filterRunnerFactory;

    public Service(IFactory<BaseType, IFilterRunner<BaseType>> filterRunnerFactory)
    {
        _filterRunnerFactory = filterRunnerFactory;
    }    
}
```

The Unity configuration looks something like this:

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
  <alias alias="BaseType" type="SomeNamespace.BaseType, SomeAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
  <alias alias="IFactory" type="SomeNamespace.IFactory`2, SomeAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
  <alias alias="IFilterRunner" type="SomeNamespace.IFilterRunner`1, SomeAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
  <alias alias="IService" type="SomeNamespace.IService, SomeAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" /> 
  <containers>
    <container>
      <register type="IFactory[BaseType,IFilterRunner]" mapTo="SomeNamespace.FilterRunnerFactory, SomeAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"/>

      <register type="IService" mapTo="SomeNamespace.Service, SomeAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral">
        <constructor>
          <param name="filterRunnerFactory" />
        </constructor>
      </register>
    </container>
  </containers>
</unity>
```

The configuration seems valid but when the WCF service itself is instantiated I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException - The
>   current type,
>   SomeNamespace.IFactory`2[SomeNamespace.BaseType,SomeNamespace.IFilterRunner`1[SomeNamespace.BaseType]],
>   is an interface and cannot be
>   constructed. Are you missing a type
>   mapping?

I’ve tried all sorts of different options but they all result in invalid configuration. Also, I have had other factory definitions that are defined to return either abstract base types or instances of types based on non-generic interfaces and they have worked fine. The difference is that this factory returns IFilterRunner - a generic interface.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance from a perplexed developer.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed your problem by specifying generic argument for IFilterRunner's alias.

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
  <alias alias="BaseType" type="SomeNamespace.BaseType, SomeAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
  <alias alias="IFactory" type="SomeNamespace.IFactory`2, SomeAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
  <alias alias="IFilterRunner" type="SomeNamespace.IFilterRunner`1[[SomeNamespace.BaseType, SomeAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral]], SomeAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
  <alias alias="IService" type="SomeNamespace.IService, SomeAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
  <containers>
    <container>
      <register type="IFactory[BaseType,IFilterRunner]" mapTo="SomeNamespace.FilterRunnerFactory, SomeAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"/>

      <register type="IService" mapTo="SomeNamespace.Service, SomeAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral">
        <constructor>
          <param name="filterRunnerFactory" />
        </constructor>
      </register>
    </container>
  </containers>
</unity>
```